# How to address users in facebook analytics server-to-server

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-analytics

Hi here's my problem:

I would like to send events to Facebook Analitycs asynchronously from my server. And my users are on iOs.

My problem is that I need to somehow identify my event server to the specific user. What I’ve seen so far are those solutions:

- **Use advertiser_id:** IDFA for iOs, it's not GDPR compliant, so I can’t store it for async server event
- **Use attribution/Mobile_cookie:** I don't know how retrieve a attribution number or mobile cookie from an iOS device? And I'm not sure if it is GDPR compliant to store it?
- **Populate and use app_user_id:** Would it be enough to track user from the server without advertiser_id or attribution?

To rephrase it:

For asynchronous event send from the server (not the mobile device), how can we identify the user properly on facebook analytics?

With  attribution/Mobile_cookie that we previously saved in database?

Or is app_user_id is enough to identify and recouple event on facebook analytics?

If you have link or information on how to do that it will help us a lot.